# Converting binary to hex

Tags: c, binary, hex

I have a binary file which contains about 2 bytes of data. I am trying to read this data and convert it into hexadecimal and then store it into an unsigned character array. I am currently able to read the binary data, but I am not sure how to convert it into hex and store it into an unsigned char array(All the data read from binary will correspond from 1-9 in Hex). So if the binary data was `00011000 00011000` I would want the unsigned char to be {18,18}. How do I go about converting to hex and then storing it into an unsigned char? This is what I have as of now:

```
FILE *binaryFile = fopen("securityFile","rb");//type binary file
        char hexData[2];
        fread(hexData,1,2,binaryFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

use sprintf (or snprintf). see http://libslack.org/manpages/snprintf.3.html